# Cannot resolve method 'setWebChromeClient(anonymous android

Tags: android, gps, android-gps

I am trying to learn building applications for Android and the first project is to view a website I've made that uses GPS localization. But when I'm trying to use `webView.setWebChromeClient(...` I'm getting the following error message: `Cannot resolve method 'setWebChromeClient(anonymous android.webkit.WebChromeClient)`.

If it will help anything, I have added the needed permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_ASSISTED_GPS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

How can I fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Delete the wrong static import on line 13 and move the call to line 31 after assigning a view to the local variable:

```
WebView view = findViewById(R.id.webView)
view.setWebChromeClient(...)
```

Comment: Thank you. But then it complains about the line I removed that was on line 13. http://i.imgur.com/rzzFkXP.jpg

Comment: Type the full view id: findViewById(R.id.webView) instead of findViewById(webView).

Comment: Thanks. But now it complains on `view` in `view.setWebChromeClient(...`. The same error message for `origin` and `callback`. And for the `GeolocationPermissions.Callback`, I get an error message that says `Expression expected`. http://i.imgur.com/HGrPfsl.jpg

Comment: Try to move your code inside the 'onCreate' method. Currently it's outside the closing bracket.

Comment: Thanks. That solved it! Now I just have to figure out how to make the application can handle the GPS localization.